# How to remove extra native dependencies from app?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I am using arcgis in my app and it bundles native dependencies that are large in size. I don't want to include the x86 dependency if it means reducing the size of the apk. How do I tell gradle to automatically exclude the x86 native library.

I tried removing it manually during the build. but it shows up again after rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I tell gradle to automatically exclude the x86 native library

Use splits:

```
android {
  // other good stuff here

  splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include 'armeabi-v7a'
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

This tells Android to build only an ARMv7 version of your APK. You would need to adjust the `include` line to list what APKs you want.

However, you may be better served using splits to just build a separate x86 APK file (have `include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'`) and ship both, so you better support x86 but still have smaller files.