# Android binary size has increased by 2x after integrating BB Dynamics SDK 8.1 as compared to 6.0

Tags: blackberry

After integrating BB Dynamics SDK 8.1 for Android, binary size has increased by 2x. I had BB Dynamics SDK 6.0 previously with my app.

My build.gradle looks like below

```
dependencies {
    .....
    .....
    implementation 'com.blackberry.blackberrydynamics:android_handheld_platform:8.1.0.37'
}
```

Using APK Analyzer below is my observations:

1. With BB Dynamics SDK 6.0
   x86/
   libgdndk.so 12.5 MB
   libsbgse.so 0 B
   armeabi-v7a/
   libgdndk.so 7.7.MB
   libsbgse.so 0 B
2. With BB Dyanmics SDK 8.1
   x86/
   libgdndk.so 17.8 MB
   libsbgse.so 1.3 MB
   armeabi-v7a/
   libgdndk.so 12.2 MB
   libsbgse.so 1.3 MB

Do I have to follow any special steps when using BB SDK 8.1 to reduce my android binary size just like older one ?

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous additions to the BlackBerry Dynamics SDK between version 6.0 and 8.1.  The following libraries have been added or consolidated in version 8.1 to make implementation easier.

- BlackBerry Dynamics SDK (core SDK that made up version 6.0)
- BlackBerry Analytics SDK
- BlackBerry Persona
- BlackBerry MTD
- Inclusion of both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries

This has caused the SDK binary to become larger.  To clarify, was your question about the increased SDK size or are you saying your binary has increased in size more than the SDK itself?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. To answer your question, my android app binary size has increased after integrating 8.1 SDK as compared to 6.0

Comment: Are you saying your app binary increased more than the increase of size of the 8.1 libraries?

Comment: @Mohm Yes around ~10 MB size has increased than the increase of size of the 8.1 libraries. I suspect it could be because of necessary dependencies required by 8.1 sdk e.g. I had to migrate Android Gradle tool from 3.4.2 to 3.6.3.

Comment: Is there anything i could do to reduce my android binary size and continue using 8.1 SDK ?

Comment: Just FYI, Binary generated for /BlackBerry_Dynamics_for_Android_r8_1_0_37/sdk/samples/AppKinetics sample app is 78.8 MB in size. I used assembleRelease gradle task and it created AppKinetics-App-debug.apk of 78.8 MB size. This is very huge size just for a sample app. I think there is something in 8.1 SDK which is causing increase in binary size.

Comment: I did another comparison of 6.0 to 8.1 and another big reason for the jump in size is the inclusion of 64 bit libraries for BlackBerry Dynamics.  So in 8.1 the APK contains:
arm64-v8a (64 bit) = 17MB
armeabi-v7a (32 bit) = 12 MB
x86 (32 bit) = 18 MB
x86_64 (54 bit) = 18 MB

Comment: Also, if you are concerned about the download size for users, you could use an Android App Bundle.  That allows Google Play to only send the binaries required by the device the app is being installed on.  https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: Thanks for the information. My BYOD Enterprise app is only available at Blackberry UEM App Store and to my knowledge it does not support Android App Bundle mechanism at the moment.

Comment: That is correct, when the binary is hosted by BlackBerry UEM only APK can be used.  Since you are deploying this to an audience where you know the devices, you might be able to remove some library variants.  For example, the x86 and x86_64 binaries are only applicable to some Chrome Books.  If you aren't deploying to those, you could strip out those library files.  Be sure to include both 32 and 64 bit arm libraries. Have a look at this post for info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122906/how-to-remove-extra-native-dependencies-from-android-app

Comment: Do you have any roadmap for UEM App Store supporting Android App Bundle in future ?

Comment: No, BlackBerry has not yet announced support for Android App Bundles in the BlackBerry UEM App Store.